# How to find and delete a session by id in MemoryStore in express-session in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I am using Node.js express and express-session.
I have saved sessions in default **MemoryStore**.
I want to find a session by sessionID in express-session.
I need to delete that session from the memory.
Its basically login out a user form existing device.
Please help

Comment: Do you want to [**destroy session**](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessiondestroycallback) ?

Comment: Yes , but only a specific sessionID

Comment: I am sure you can do something like `request.sessionStore.destroy(sessionId, callback);` but you need to know the sessionId

Comment: Thanku very much. It works !!

Answer (score 0):

From official [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessiondestroycallback):

**Session.destroy(callback)**

Destroys the session and will unset the req.session property. Once complete, the callback will be invoked.

```
req.session.destroy(function(err) {
  // cannot access session here
})
```